# How to pass data between Safari and Native application

Tags: ios, swift, safari

At the moment, I'm using the native Safari application to show a web app to users on iPad devices. Unfortunately in versions of iOS 11.04 and greater, we have lost the ability to play sounds from a Safari Web Clip. Has anyone run into this issue before? How did you solve it?

One of the solutions I played around with was creating a native application that could play sounds when something occurred inside of Safari. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how would I achieve that?

Comment: You need create custom URL Scheme in native app. And then just call it from web app, it will launch you native app and do what you want. Or you can send notification with sound to your app

Comment: @canister_exister If I use the url_scheme, will the app remain in the background or will it open each time? In regards to your second suggestion, can you send a notification from safari to a native app?

Comment: url scheme will open app. safari just work with server sides, so you can send notification from server side.